# how to return promise in firebase set()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to receive success if data is pushed correctly to firebase or catch an error if rejected. I tried such a code:

```
db.push().set(todo).then(snap => {
      console.log(snap);

    });
```

but SNAP, callback, IS UNDEFINED . How do I need to use promises here?

Comment: What returns undefined?  Can you edit the code in your question to illustrate how you are observing this?

Comment: snap return undefined, what do you want edit? everything clear here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The .then does not return a snapshot of the data -- you will need to do a "once" snapshot of the data within the callback

```
db.push().set(values).then(() => {
  console.log('Successfully set');

  db.once('value').then((snap) => {
    console.log(snap);
  });
});
```

Comment: So if then is run, the set is successfully or I need to read value in order to know if set was successfully?

Comment: @DanielJosePadillaPeña When the .set().then() is run firebase added the data without issue's. So you can assume it has been set.

Comment: Reading back the data is pointless tho, since you already have the values in the set method..If the set is called the data was succesfully set, otherwise call the get error method.

Comment: @AlfonsoBriceño I'm here because I need the ID of the data I just saved so I can perform some UI interactions that depend heavily on either a local Id for local data or the remote one for saved data.